# openni_kinect dosen't publish anything in the topics or rviz

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm very new to ROS so bare with me a bit, I've just installed Electric on Ubuntu 11.04 on an Toshiba L650 laptop (ATI VGA)

I've installed opennni_kinect using the package

As I understand all I need to do is just to connect the kinect and start the openni_camera node so I did that using "roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch" and that kept on doing some stuff and stopped at

[ INFO] [1317816184.407080225]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1317816184.410629139]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame'

so I assumed everything is ok then followed the instruction to view the images on rviz but got nothing except a status warning in the point cloud2 screen in front of Topic saying "No messages received"

I checked using rostopic hz and rostopic echo for /camera/rgb/points but there is nothing there, also the global frame status indicates the status to be ok but there is nothing showing on the screen at all

I'm I missing something or is there a conflict with ATI driver or something? is there anything else rather than roscore should be running or is there any other steps before I run the node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11423/openni_kinect-dosen%27t-publish-anything-in-the-topics-or-rviz/) by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try running `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`; things have be re-arranged a bit in electric.

Do the messages printed to the console indicate that the device is connected?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2011-10-17**:
After multiple retries I finally figured out the problem with rviz not starting, although I'm still unable to use see what I wan't in rviz but at least the openni driver does publish data in the topics, I'll just have to work on using them without using rviz

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2011-10-12**:
I think you're right, I tried your suggestion and used rostopic echo to listen to rgb/image_raw and ir/image_raw and I got all those numbers running on the screen, so I think the driver is ok now, unfortunately rviz gives some new "Segmentation fault" so I can't see what those numbers are, thanks

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2011-10-10**:
Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I didn't got to try it yet as I work with Kinect in the uni and I was busy with some literature review, I'll have some time tomorrow to work on the Kinect and try out the different launch file

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting the same problem very often. It may or may not be related to what you're seeing, but here's my take:

My observation is that it helps to quit out of all ros processes (incl. rviz) before starting the openni launch file. Once the launch file starts, wait for a couple of seconds until the driver is fully up and running, and then start rviz. It seems that if something subscribes to the topics before the openni driver is ready, things break down.

It sometimes a couple of retries before it actually works.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2011-10-10**:
Thanks Ben_S for indicating that the launch file itself is the problem, for I feared that there might be some hardware incompatibility on my laptop, I'll try modifying the launch file or using older version

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2011-10-10**:
Thanks, I did tried to quit everything (Including roscore) and start over and waited for a while to make sure that the node is up and running and no other tasks are pending or in processes

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2011-10-09**:
I am having these problems too. It often takes 5 to 10 tries to start up the openni-driver. It also doesnt matter for me if i use the new openni_launch or the older openni_camera launch files. It seems to be known and posted here already: https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac/ticket/42 Hope for a fix.